# Xamarin Walkthrough Binding an iOS ObjC Library w NSInvalidArgumentException Error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have followed the walkthrough for linking an ObjC library in Xamarin from [their site](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/).

I'm getting an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error when I close the colorpicker view.

I found a couple typos and minor fixes to get the example application to run with an error when closing the InfColorPicker view.

One minor modification I had to make was to change CGImageRef* to CGImage in the StructsAndEnums.cs file generated by Objective Sharper.

```
    [DllImport ("__Internal")]
    static extern unsafe CGImageRef* createSaturationBrightnessSquareContentImageWithHue (float hue);

    [DllImport ("__Internal")]
    static extern unsafe CGImageRef* createHSVBarContentImage (InfComponentIndex barComponentIndex, float[] hsv);
```

to

```
    [DllImport ("__Internal")]
    static extern unsafe CGImage createSaturationBrightnessSquareContentImageWithHue (float hue);

    [DllImport ("__Internal")]
    static extern unsafe CGImage createHSVBarContentImage (InfComponentIndex barComponentIndex, float[] hsv);
```

I tried disabling BitCode generation in the XCode library after I found documentation on doing that for a Swift framework. I still get the same error.

Error I get after tapping done to close the view:
[image: NSInvalidArgumentException]

[My source](https://github.com/kingbin/InfColorPickerSample) for this project.
I can add a branch that includes the BitCode generation disabled if that would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Weak Delegate generated from Objective Sharpie output. I had switched the ViewController to use a WeakDelegate instead of a Subclassed strong delegate. I needed to handle the colorPickerControllerDidFinish message in the ViewController.

Adding the following function to the ViewController fixed the error I was getting when the user tapped "Done".

```
    [Export("colorPickerControllerDidFinish:")]
    public void ColorPickerControllerDidFinish(InfColorPickerController controller)
    {
        View.BackgroundColor = controller.ResultColor;
        DismissViewController(false, null);

    }
```